# Refine a WHERE condition on ORACLE query to staging tables

Tags: oracle, where-clause, linked-tables

I am looking for some assistance with refining a `WHERE` condition on a SQL query to a set of linked Oracle data staging tables.

One table is for case data, containing meta-data about the record. There is only one record per case on this table. There is a flag column on this table that marks the case data as `Processed` once the data is read and sent to another database. 
case_staging_table

```
CASE_NUMBER CASE_DETAILS PARENT_ID_NUMBER PROCESSED_FLAG
0001        First Case   X0001            NULL
0002        Second Case  X0002            NULL
0003        Third Case   X0003            Processed
```

The second table is for attachment data, and contains meta-data about the file attachments that are linked to the case data. There are possibly multiple records per case on this table. There is a flag column on this table that marks the attachment as Sent if the resulting file is transmitted to a server.
attachment_staging_table

```
ID_NUMBER PARENT_ID_NUMBER ATTACHMENT_NAME               ATTACHMENT_SENT_FLAG
A0001     X0001            First Case Attachment 1.docx  N
A0002     X0001            First Case Attachment 2.docx  N
A0003     X0001            First Case Attachment 3.docx  Y
A0004     X0003            Third Case Attachment.docx    Y
```

What I need to do is construct a `WHERE` condition on a query where I only pull in case records where the case has NOT been Processed, and ALL attachment records contain a `Y` or a `NULL` in the `ATTACHMENT_SENT_FLAG` column (a `NULL` would be present if the case record contains no attachments). If any one of the related records in the attachment staging table has a `N` in the `ATTACHMENT_SENT_FLAG` column, I don’t want the case record to appear in the query results.

In this scenario :

- Case Number `0001` has not been processed, has three attachments associated with it, and only one of the attachments has been sent to the server.
- Case Number `0002` has not been processed, and has no attachments associated with it.
- Case Number `0003` has already been processed.

The results of the query at this stage should only include Case Number `0002`, as it has not been processed and does not have to wait for any attachments. The query results should not contain Case Number `0001`, as two of the attachments are not yet ready, and should not contain Case Number `0003`, as it has already been processed.

My current query has the following WHERE condition:

```
SELECT 
    case.staging_table.CASE_NUMBER,
    case_staging_table.CASE_DETAILS,
    attachment_staging_table.ATTACHMENT_NAME
FROM
    case_staging_table
    LEFT JOIN attachment_staging_table 
        ON case_staging_table.PARENT-ID = attachment_staging_table.PARENT_ID
WHERE 
    case_staging_table.PROCESSED_FLAG IS NULL
    AND (
        attachment_staging_table.ATTACHMENT_SENT_FLAG = ‘Y’
        OR attachment_staging_table.ATTACHMENT_SENT_FLAG IS NULL
    )
```

This `WHERE` condition however would still process Case Number `0001` and flag it as Processed as soon as it hits the third attachment that was sent to the server.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter `attachment_staging_table` records which have `ATTACHMENT_SENT_FLAG = 'N'`, like this:

```
SELECT 
    case_staging_table.CASE_NUMBER,
    case_staging_table.CASE_DETAILS,
    attachment_staging_table.ATTACHMENT_NAME
FROM
    case_staging_table
    LEFT JOIN attachment_staging_table 
        ON case_staging_table.PARENT_ID_NUMBER = attachment_staging_table.PARENT_ID_NUMBER
WHERE 
    case_staging_table.PROCESSED_FLAG IS NULL
    AND case_staging_table.PARENT_ID_NUMBER not in 
        ( select x.PARENT_ID_NUMBER
          from attachment_staging_table x      
          where x.ATTACHMENT_SENT_FLAG = 'N'
            )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and concise response! I tested it this morning and it works very well!